# Match letters and numbers, doesn't match numbers only

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I need to match just numbers and letters but I don't want to match numbers only.

So, "a1", should match, so does "1a". "a" should match. "1", "1111", "987", etc shouldn't match.

```
<?php
echo preg_match('~^(?![0-9])[0-9a-z]$~', 'a1') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 1
echo preg_match('~^(?![0-9])[0-9a-z]$~', '1a') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 1
echo preg_match('~^(?![0-9])[0-9a-z]$~', '1') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 0
echo preg_match('~^(?![0-9])[0-9a-z]$~', 'a') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 1
```

How could i achieve these results?

UPDATE:

It's working:

```
<?php
echo preg_match('~^(?=[a-z]+)|(?![0-9]+)[0-9a-z]+$~', 'a1') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 1
echo preg_match('~^(?=[a-z]+)|(?![0-9]+)[0-9a-z]+$~', '1a') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 1
echo preg_match('~^(?=[a-z]+)|(?![0-9]+)[0-9a-z]+$~', '1') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 0
echo preg_match('~^(?=[a-z]+)|(?![0-9]+)[0-9a-z]+$~', 'a') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 1

echo PHP_EOL;

echo preg_match('~[0-9]*[a-z]+[0-9a-z]*~', 'a1') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 1
echo preg_match('~[0-9]*[a-z]+[0-9a-z]*~', '1a') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 1
echo preg_match('~[0-9]*[a-z]+[0-9a-z]*~', '1') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 0
echo preg_match('~[0-9]*[a-z]+[0-9a-z]*~', 'a') . PHP_EOL; // I expect 1
```

Thanks you guys!

Comment: Add a `+` after `[0-9a-z]`.

Comment: Yes, i forgot the plus sign. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome Thom Thom Thom! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a pattern containing this :

```
[0-9]*[a-z]+[0-9a-z]*
```

This should match at least one letter and any number of digits.

Comment: Your way is much more readable. Lookbehind is confusing, please look at my update. Thank you very much!